# Populate field with address jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I"m trying to populate an address field with the returned data from an ajax/json request. The response for the address is

```
  "MKT_PHYS_ADR_LINE":{"ArrayOfstringItem":["Marlow International","Parkway"]},
```

I'm using the following to populate the  field on my form. If I use ArrayOfstringItem as below, it populates the field with a value, but not the correct one as there is another ArrayOfstringItem from the returned data.

```
else if(fieldCompare=='ArrayOfstringItem')
    {
    jQuery("#input_35_47_1").val(companyResponse[field]).change();
    }
```

How do I specifically target the MKT_PHYS_ADR_LINE?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your response is `res = "MKT_PHYS_ADR_LINE":{"ArrayOfstringItem":["Marlow International","Parkway"]};`

You can do something like this:

```
jQuery("#input_35_47_1").val(res.MKT_PHYS_ADR_LINE.ArrayOfstringItem[0] + " " + res.MKT_PHYS_ADR_LINE.ArrayOfstringItem[1]);
```